# Using jQuery plugin called jQuery File Tree

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, treelist

Do not know if you know this plugin but basically it displays a tree.
I'm having trouble using it, and would like your help to use this plugin.

[This link](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/) has a presentation of the plugin.

Basically I have the project groups and projects where I display the tree, each project within their respective group. And once the user clicks on the group, the group is expanded showing all projects that group.

[Here](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/fileTree/demo/) is an example of use.

**My environment is asp.net (C #)**

I would like to use this plugin to display the group's projects and projects under the tree:

Follow the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/DH5sc/4/) for a code, as far as I could do.
I would like to view the ul and li tags in the tree.

Comment: what is the problem exactly, that you are having?

Comment: What problems are you having?  You're not providing many details in regards to the issue you're having.

Comment: I am not able to use this plugin.
I have a list and <UI> <il> ...
See my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/DH5sc/


In the parameters, there is a folder ... script: 'jqueryFileTree.asp', did not understand.

And another detail .. root: '/some/folder/', was also confused the purpose of this property.

How can I make my list and <ui> <il> that are group projects and project as a tree like the example below: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/fileTree/demo/

Answer (score 0):

The FileTree plugin uses a folder structure on the server to build a tree on the front-end. The `root` parameter is supplied to the script specified in the `script` parameter. The script uses the `root` parameter to build a child tree of "files" under that folder.

That means, you have to create a script (e.g. HttpHandler) and supply the URL of that script in the `script` parameter. In your script, you use the `root` parameter to retrieve and return child elements.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But if I want to use a ul li structure to generate this tree, I can not ?
How can I do this?

Comment: You can, and you do that in your script (php, aspx, ashx, etc). Your script gets the "root" parameter supplied in the AJAX call, then uses that to generate the HTML for the UL list. Hope that helps.